# Suddenly my instance stopped responding to my incoming connections for mysql connections

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I had installed mysql on gcp instance for dev and test purposes. Everything was working perfect but suddenly started getting connection timed out error. Firewall is opened on for MySQL connections. It was working perfectly, suddenly it stopped.

Here is the log for the connection

```
{
 inserted: "xxxxxx"
 jsonPayload: {
  connection: {
   dest_ip: "10.142.0.2"    
   dest_port: 3306    
   protocol: 6    
   src_ip: "54.87.222.27"    
   src_port: 52638    
  }
  disposition: "ALLOWED"   
  instance: {
   project_id: "xxxxxxxx"    
   region: "us-east1"    
   vm_name: "stockarea-server"    
   zone: "us-east1-b"    
  }
  remote_location: {
   city: "Ashburn"    
   continent: "America"    
   country: "usa"    
   region: "Virginia"    
  }
  rule_details: {
   action: "ALLOW"    
   direction: "INGRESS"    
   ip_port_info: [
    0: {
     ip_protocol: "TCP"      
     port_range: [
      0: "3306"       
     ]
    }
    1: {
     ip_protocol: "UDP"      
     port_range: [
      0: "3306"       
     ]
    }
   ]
   priority: 1000    
   reference: "network:default/firewall:heroku-sql"    
   source_range: [
    0: "0.0.0.0/0"     
   ]
  }
  vpc: {
   project_id: "xxxxxxxx"    
   subnetwork_name: "default"    
   vpc_name: "default"    
  }
 }
 logName: "projects/pxxxxxxx/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Ffirewall"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-05-22T18:25:57.341545693Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   location: "us-east1-b"    
   project_id: "xxxxxxxx"    
   subnetwork_id: "5137290941342062105"    
   subnetwork_name: "default"    
  }
  type: "gce_subnetwork"   
 }
 timestamp: "2020-05-22T18:25:45.934585080Z"  
}
```

I have MySQL users having permission to get access for different IP address:

```
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| client           | %         |
| stockarea        | %         |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
```

UPDATE:
I saw MySQL error.log file and saw somebody attacked and has somehow crashed the database. It was throwing error `packet getting out of order`. I reinstalled the MySQL for now to solve this and continue my development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I tried to ping your external IP and it works. So all 80, 443, and 3306. I believe your firewall is setup correctly, Please make sure your service is running and listening to those ports.

And finally, please be aware that you should sanitize private inforamtion such as ip address and project ID in public forum